# php getting array index

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

Hi i have an array and the output are as following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat1_id] => 1
            [sub_cat1_id] => 1065
            [b_subcat_name] => Asian
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat3_id] => 1
            [sub_cat3_id] => 1011
            [b_subcat_name] => Barbeque
        )

)
```

i am using for loop to output this data, but how can i get `sub_cat1_id` and `sub_cat2_id` name to be output on html? Thanks

Comment: You should show your for loop's code too

Answer (score 1):

you have to loop inside the loop and get the keyName

```
            foreach($UpperLoop as $l1)
              foreach($l1 as $l2)
                 { here you will get the key Name }
```